# Mailing in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, email

Hi i have a problem in mailing in the C#.net. I want to mail to the email address but i do not want to open the Outlook. Is there any procedure to do this. Please help to mail in c#.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need access to an SMTP server.  If you have that add the following to your web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network 
             host="relayServerHostname" 
             port="portNumber"
             userName="username"
             password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And take a look at .NET's [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class.  here is an example of how to craete a basic MailMesage object:

```
   MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
      "jane@contoso.com",
      "ben@contoso.com",
      "Quarterly data report.",
      "See the attached spreadsheet.");
```

To send the message you will use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class (which is conviniently configured from your web.config if you added the xml i suggested above.  Example:

```
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
   client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Whats the meaning of the relayhostname its a gmail,yahoomail or my hostname where i want to upload website. how can i find out the port number

Comment: This will be your SMTP server address.  The port will typically be 25 but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your putting a `mailto:...` link on your form. This will always open the default mail client on the user's PC.

What you need to do is have a contact form and send the email via the server.

For more information see the following website:

> [System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)
>   [How do I send a plain text email? (System.Net.Mail)](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.1.aspx)

For reference:

> [System.Net.Mail Namespace (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the kind plug (systemNetMail.com is my website). --Dave

Comment: @dave - it's an excellent resource. I send all my hosting customers there (and previously the System.Web.Mail way back when...).

Answer (score 0):

The System.Net.Mail namespace was meant to do this; check this out: http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Comment: Thanks for the kind plug (systemNetMail.com is my website).

Comment: @Dave no problem, comes in handily when trying to help other users.  Thanks for creating it.